# Can't create glassfish-web.xml in my web project (Glassfish/Netbeans)

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I have a Java project that uses Java EE 7 and Glassfish 4.1

When I add a new Glassfish Descriptor to the project (via the right-click menu), it doesn't give me the ability to change the name of the `xml` file. It forces it to be `sun-web.xml` which is an old legacy format. I'm trying to use `glassfish-web.xml`.

How can I make it add the correct file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work if you are using Netbeans 8. If you are using an older version of Netbeans you should update to the latest version.

You can manually create a new xml file named `glassfish-web.xml` (or rename the `sun-web.xml`) and insert the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

This is the content Netbeans creates by default.

Comment: I'm running Netbeans 8+, but your workaround fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Is it sufficient to specify `GlassFish Application Server 3.1` , `Servlet 3.0`, and `glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd` in the given DTD while using GlassFish Server **4.1** which uses Java EE 7 and Servlet 3.1?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had resolved it.

It seems bundled GlassFish is wrong.
You should download the GlassFish4.1 Full version and replace the bundled GlassFish with it.